# server gets crash after upgrading ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have successfully upgraded my ruby version from `1.9.3` to `2.0.0`.

After upgrading I run the following command:

```
heroku run "ruby -v"
```

I got the following result:

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]
```

So it says that it has successfully upgraded.

But my server is going down after doing this upgrade.

I am pasting my log below:

```
2014-06-04T09:56:31.146129+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-04T09:56:31.147218+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-04T09:56:32.117363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.12430334.9fb26edd-74ed-4fc5-b711-3aa4046b26e0 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.00
2014-06-04T09:56:32.117588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.12430334.9fb26edd-74ed-4fc5-b711-3aa4046b26e0 sample#memory_total=207.51MB sample#memory_rss=203.38MB sample#memory_cache=2.49MB sample#memory_swap=1.64MB sample#memory_pgpgin=71538pages sample#memory_pgpgout=18835pages
2014-06-04T09:56:32.754654+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-04T09:56:32.755480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-04T09:56:32.126480+00:00 heroku[web.3]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-04T09:56:32.127116+00:00 heroku[web.3]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-04T09:56:33.248631+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2014-06-04T09:56:33.249565+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-04T09:56:32.747712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-04T09:56:31.137464+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-04T09:56:31.549629+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2014-06-04T09:56:31.549785+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2014-06-04T09:56:33.036445+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Process exited with status 22
2014-06-04T09:56:32.971809+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2014-06-04T09:56:32.972159+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2014-06-04T09:56:35.033388+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process exited with status 137
2014-06-04T09:56:32.117824+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-04T09:56:33.881617+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-06-04T09:56:33.236422+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-04T09:56:40.077607+00:00 app[web.3]: I, [2014-06-04T09:56:40.077483 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-06-04T09:56:40.509178+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-06-04T09:56:40.312391+00:00 app[web.2]: I, [2014-06-04T09:56:40.312184 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-06-04T09:56:39.727072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 5550 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-06-04T09:56:36.836467+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 18762 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-06-04T09:56:37.693789+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 39531 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-06-04T09:56:42.622779+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-04T09:56:42.622598 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-06-04T09:56:39.840965+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work QUEUE=*`
2014-06-04T09:56:43.918330+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.12430334.af5dfd71-5358-4752-897f-dc4aab994f4e sample#memory_total=17.10MB sample#memory_rss=17.10MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=8392pages sample#memory_pgpgout=4014pages
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808497+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:70:in `[]': invalid number of elements (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808509+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:70:in `connection_url_to_hash'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808512+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:34:in `block in resolve_string_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808515+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:33:in `fetch'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808517+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:33:in `resolve_string_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808519+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808526+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808528+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808531+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808533+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808535+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808537+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808542+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808544+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808546+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808549+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808551+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808553+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808556+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808559+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808565+00:00 app[web.2]:     from config.ru:4:in `require'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808567+00:00 app[web.2]:     from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808569+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808571+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808574+00:00 app[web.2]:     from config.ru:1:in `new'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808576+00:00 app[web.2]:     from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808578+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808580+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808582+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `call'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808598+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `build_app!'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808601+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808602+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808605+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808606+00:00 app[web.2]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.626705+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=web.3 dyno=heroku.12430334.0f21966e-2446-4c53-ac74-eb546f873df3 sample#memory_total=92.60MB sample#memory_rss=92.60MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=27839pages sample#memory_pgpgout=4134pages
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665273+00:00 app[web.3]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:70:in `[]': invalid number of elements (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665282+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:70:in `connection_url_to_hash'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665285+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:34:in `block in resolve_string_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665287+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:33:in `fetch'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665291+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:33:in `resolve_string_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665312+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665314+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665316+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665321+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665322+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665324+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665326+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665327+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665329+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665330+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665332+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665334+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665335+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665336+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665346+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665351+00:00 app[web.3]:     from config.ru:4:in `require'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665352+00:00 app[web.3]:     from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665354+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665355+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665363+00:00 app[web.3]:     from config.ru:1:in `new'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665374+00:00 app[web.3]:     from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665376+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665377+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665379+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `call'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665380+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `build_app!'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665382+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665383+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665385+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2014-06-04T09:56:46.665389+00:00 app[web.3]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748892+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:70:in `[]': invalid number of elements (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748902+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:70:in `connection_url_to_hash'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748905+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:34:in `block in resolve_string_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748907+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:33:in `fetch'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748910+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:33:in `resolve_string_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748912+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748915+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748917+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748919+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748921+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748922+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748924+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748928+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748930+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748931+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748932+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748934+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748938+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748939+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748941+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748944+00:00 app[web.1]:     from config.ru:4:in `require'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748946+00:00 app[web.1]:     from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748947+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748951+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748952+00:00 app[web.1]:     from config.ru:1:in `new'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748953+00:00 app[web.1]:     from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748957+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748959+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748962+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `call'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.748996+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `build_app!'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.749000+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.749002+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.749003+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2014-06-04T09:56:47.749005+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2014-06-04T09:56:48.116074+00:00 heroku[web.3]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-04T09:56:46.479976+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-04T09:56:44.130022+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.12430334.895ce308-1bbc-42c7-afc3-e9c88013f3d8 sample#memory_total=82.06MB sample#memory_rss=82.06MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=25086pages sample#memory_pgpgout=4078pages
2014-06-04T09:56:46.469081+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-04T09:56:49.220761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-04T09:56:49.201749+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
2014-06-04T09:56:49.200196+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2014-06-04T09:56:49.202011+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2014-06-04T09:56:49.202079+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2014-06-04T09:56:50.136727+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/permits/ host=www.movingpermits.com request_id=fa3070a0-6c4f-45ac-8404-8b310c218858 fwd="8.18.111.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-04T09:56:50.157093+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/permits/ host=www.movingpermits.com request_id=dac4a7ee-2411-4736-9476-7748eb72f5ce fwd="8.18.111.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-04T09:56:50.158149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/permits/ host=www.movingpermits.com request_id=5fe7c1d4-5410-48cb-b203-21f049a88154 fwd="8.18.111.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-04T09:56:50.745419+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/permits/ host=www.movingpermits.com request_id=3f1f83fb-5176-43ae-9b53-8b540d83dbe8 fwd="209.116.78.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-04T09:56:50.755660+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path=/ host=moving-permits.herokuapp.com request_id=2bbd87bf-5394-4a09-951d-918d6bfdd809 fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-04T09:56:51.226540+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2014-06-04T09:56:51.666416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path=/ host=moving-permits.herokuapp.com request_id=6e27bd39-806a-4291-8466-5eaa8746a927 fwd="54.251.34.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-04T09:56:48.110051+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-04T09:56:49.208938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-04T09:56:51.211233+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am using `rails 3.2.18`.

Comment: How did you go about upgrading your server?

Comment: by specifying the ruby version  in my gem file

Comment: good, just wanted to check you hadn't tried to do anything weird. I'm afraid I don't have any useful advice for you other than the standard, did you check you ran `db:migrate` e.t.c. (it doesn't look like that from the logs)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the line to focus on.

```
2014-06-04T09:56:44.808497+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:70:in `[]': invalid number of elements (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
```

To solve this make sure your initializers and/or your DATABASE_URL environment variable aren't incorrectly concatenating strings (query parameters) to the end, such as a ?mode=test&ssl_cert=?pool=25.

I had a DATABASE_URL with query params added in the heroku config but in an initializer for a sidekiq worker I was appending and additional param of '?pool=5'. In prior versions this seemed to parse properly, or more likely just dropped off the value.

After changing my DATABASE_URL to properly chain query params with a leading ? and then & to join params the database connected successfully.